# Serialized object to ajax/json undefined

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a List MyModel using AJAX/JSON to controller and noticed that the objects are all passing as 'undefined':

[Form Post Data]

```
undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=
```

Here is my sample code:

[Model]

```
public class ICalEvent
{
    public string EventTitle { get; set; }
    public string EventAbstract { get; set; }
    public string EventStartDate { get; set; }
    public string EventEndDate { get; set; }
    public string VenueTitle { get; set; }
    public string VenueAddress { get; set; }

}
```

[Controller]

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult JsonCreateICalEvents(IList<ICalEvent> iCalEvents)
{
    Dictionary<String, String> status = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    if (iCalEvents != null)
    {
        status.Add("status", "success");
    }
    else
    {
        status.Add("status", "No objects passed!");
    }

    return Json(status);
}
```

[View]

```
List<ICalEvent> iCalEvents = new List<ICalEvent>();
.
.
.
ICalEvent iCalEvent = new ICalEvent
{
    EventTitle = eventTitle,
    EventAbstract = eventAbstract,
    EventStartDate = screeningDate.ToShortDateString(),
    EventEndDate = screeningDate.ToShortDateString(),
    VenueTitle = venueTitle,
    VenueAddress = venueAddress
};
.
.
.
iCalEvents.Add(iCalEvent);


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ical-events").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("JsonCreateICalEvents", "ICalEvent")',
                data: @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(iCalEvents,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings { StringEscapeHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.StringEscapeHandling.Default })),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status == "success") {
                        alert("Worked!");
                    }
                    else if(data.status != "success")
                    {
                        alert("Did not work!");
                    }
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I inspect the AJAX JSON data before post looks good:

```
[{"EventTitle":"Opening Night: Keep the Change","EventAbstract":"Under the guise of a New York romantic comedy, Keep the Change does something quite radical: In a refreshingly honest way it portrays two adults on the autistic spectrum. David desperately wants to be seen as “normal,” but Sarah accepts who she is. Together they navigate the vicissitudes of a burgeoning relationship. Writer/director Rachel Israel has an obvious affection for her characters, which infuses this poignant and funny film from the first frame to the last.","EventStartDate":"7/20/2017","EventEndDate":"7/20/2017","VenueTitle":"Castro Theatre","VenueAddress":"429 Castro Street"},{"EventTitle":"More Alive Than Dead","EventAbstract":"The legacy of Sigmund Freud is a slippery subject indeed. Whatever your views on the founder of psychoanalysis, there is no denying his incalculable influence on science, art, culture and even language. More Alive Than Dead explores opinions on Freud over the years with a sense of humor accompanied by hilarious animation. Experts assess his influence on psychoanalysis, neurology, literature, the LGBT community, the economy and feminism. In other words, just about everything.","EventStartDate":"7/21/2017","EventEndDate":"7/21/2017","VenueTitle":"Castro Theatre","VenueAddress":"429 Castro Street"},...]
```

Given that everything posts as undefined my controller receives null data. Any idea what I am missing? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Add `contentType: 'application/json'` in the ajax call setting. You are using json data and default content type is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'

Comment: You also need to stringify the data (using `JSON.Stringify(..)` since your posting an array of complex objects and not using indexers (although its unclear what the point of passing back exactly the same model that your just sent to the client)

Comment: @shakib I originally had that parameter in place but it would break the MVC route. In the end it appears to worry without it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I believe the SerializeObject method I have in place accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to assign your iCalEvents a perimeter name that should correspond to the action's parameter name. So, you should update ajax request to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com',
    data: { iCalEvents: [{"EventTitle":"Opening Night: Keep the Change","EventAbstract":"Under the guise of a New York romantic comedy, Keep the Change does something quite radical: In a refreshingly honest way it portrays two adults on the autistic spectrum. David desperately wants to be seen as “normal,” but Sarah accepts who she is. Together they navigate the vicissitudes of a burgeoning relationship. Writer/director Rachel Israel has an obvious affection for her characters, which infuses this poignant and funny film from the first frame to the last.","EventStartDate":"7/20/2017","EventEndDate":"7/20/2017","VenueTitle":"Castro Theatre","VenueAddress":"429 Castro Street"},{"EventTitle":"More Alive Than Dead","EventAbstract":"The legacy of Sigmund Freud is a slippery subject indeed. Whatever your views on the founder of psychoanalysis, there is no denying his incalculable influence on science, art, culture and even language. More Alive Than Dead explores opinions on Freud over the years with a sense of humor accompanied by hilarious animation. Experts assess his influence on psychoanalysis, neurology, literature, the LGBT community, the economy and feminism. In other words, just about everything.","EventStartDate":"7/21/2017","EventEndDate":"7/21/2017","VenueTitle":"Castro Theatre","VenueAddress":"429 Castro Street"}]},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.status == "success") {
            alert("Worked!");
        }
        else if(data.status != "success")
        {
            alert("Did not work!");
        }
    }
```

});

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing piece and resolved the issue!